# Validate form fields (ajax call included in validation function) before submitting the values

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

i am using Spring mvc in a application and it has a submission form.The form has for example - firstName, lastName fields and a submit button (type="submit").
what i am trying to achieve is when i click submit button , it should perform the validation on the fields (firstName, lastName) and than the submit button should submit the value.

i tried the below code:

### home.jsp

```
    <form:form id="formDataBean" method="post" modelAttribute="formDataBean" action="submit" class="form" >

        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" value="${firstName}"/>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" value="${lastName}"/>
        <input id="submitButtonid" type="submit" value="Submit"/> 

    </form:form> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#formDataBean").submit(function( event ) {

         // validation code below
         var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
         var lastName = $("#lastName").val();

         var infoToValidate = new Array();  
         infoToValidate.push(firstName);
         infoToValidate.push(lastName);

         // ajax call to controller to validate the values

         $.ajax({

              url : "validate",
              type : "GET",
              data : "infoToValidate=" + infoToValidate,  //Stringified Json Object

              success : function(data) {  

                     if(data == valid){
                     //i want to re invoke the submit button without any code
                     $("#formDataBean").submit(function( event ) {}
                     }

                      if(data == inValid){
                     //i want to prevent the submit button action to propagate further 
                     event.preventDefault();        
                     }
              },
              error : function() {
                    alert("fail");
              }
             });
    }
}
</script>
```

### HomeController.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitInfo(FormDataBean formDataBean, Model model){

        // submission code 

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validate" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String validateResult(@RequestParam String[] infoToValidate) {

        // validation code
            if valid{
             return "valid";
            } else{
             return "inValid";
            }
    }
```

**Here is the Problem :**
if i wont call ajax in validation function than the code will work fine (first validation will happen and than if the values 
are valid it will submit the result calling the controller submit method )
but if i use ajax call in the validation (which is required for my case) as shown above than both the events are getting started simultaneously
both events means : the ajax call and the submission code in the controller and here it goes wrong.

Comment: Your stringified json does not happen just because your comment says so. Also test the values for blank before wasting a call. You need to prevent the form submission with a preventDefault too

Comment: @mplungjan Hi, thanks for the comment, yes i am checking the blank or empty before passing it to ajax and if its blank or empty than i am calling event.preventDefault(), the problem is both controller submit method and ajax call for controller validateResult method is getting invoke simultaneously.

Comment: You need to call event.preventDefault before the ajax call of course

Comment: yes of course i will call event.preventDefault() but only if there is blank or empty value but what if firstName and lastName is not valid ? than it should call ajax to call controller validate() method to further validate firstName and lastName for other logic. am i correct ?

Comment: you cannot do the AJAX UNLESS you call preventDefault in the submit event since the form will be submitted while you are attempting the ajax

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, your comment helped me alot, can you please guide me seeing my home.jsp code if the $("#formDataBean").submit(function( event ) {} is valid or not ? i tried the above mentioned code and the .trigger() function but its not working on success of the ajax call, am i doing something wrong there ?

Comment: I'll look when I get to a computer

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is not recommended to use async false, but it is the solution here if you insist on server side validation before submitting.

The better solution is to just submit the form and return an error if more errors were found on the server

```
$(function(){
  $("#formDataBean").submit(function(event) {
    // validation code below
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    if ($.trim(firstName+lastName) ==="") {
      alert("Please enter first name and last name");
      $("#firstName").focus();
      return false;
    }
    var vals = { "firstName":firstName,"lastName":lastName};
    // ajax call to controller to validate the values
    $.ajax({
      url  : "validate", 
      async: false,
      type : "GET",
      data : JSON.stringify(vals);
      success : function(data) {  
        if (data == "inValid") {
          alert("Names are invalid");
          return false; // cancel submit        
        },
      error : function() {
        alert("Error occurred");
        return false; // cancel submit        
      }
    });
    return true; // allow submission
  });
});
```